# Getting error related to instance of for abstract model class when trying to override function via plugin

Tags: magento2

Following is the error I am getting when trying to override validate() via a plugin

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drummondgolf\Subtotalwithdiscount\Plugin\ProductPlugin::afterValidate() must be an instance of Drummondgolf\Subtotalwithdiscount\Plugin\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel, instance of Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address\Interceptor given, called in /var/www/html/dg/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146 and defined in /var/www/html/dg/app/code/Drummondgolf/Subtotalwithdiscount/Plugin/ProductPlugin.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/dg/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Drummondgolf\Subtotalwithdiscount\Plugin\ProductPlugin->afterValidate(Object(Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address\Interceptor), false, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor)) #1 /var/www/html/dg/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Add in /var/www/html/dg/app/code/Drummondgolf/Subtotalwithdiscount/Plugin/ProductPlugin.php on line 16
```

I am trying to override validate() of

`/var/www/html/dg/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Address.php`

via plugin but getting above error.

I have already tried with preference but not getting called in frontend

**Plugin code**

```
namespace Drummondgolf\Subtotalwithdiscount\Plugin; 

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class ProductPlugin  {      
public function afterValidate(Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)
    {    
        $address = $model;
        if (!$address instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address) {
            if ($model->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                $address = $model->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
            } else {
                $address = $model->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            }
        }

        if ('payment_method' == $this->getAttribute() && !$address->hasPaymentMethod()) {
            $address->setPaymentMethod($model->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod());
        }

        // This function is from vendor
        $baseTotalWithDiscount = $address->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getDiscountAmount();
        $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($baseTotalWithDiscount);

        return parent::validate($address);  
    } }
```

di.xml code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address">
    <plugin name="Mageplaza-yourmodule-product-block" type="Drummondgolf\Subtotalwithdiscount\Plugin\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="5" />
</type>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, Magento caches the data of the files in `var/` and `generated/` folder, so if you clear the `var/` and `generated/` content then Magento will regenerate the interceptor.

```
rm -rf var/ generated/
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Not working....

Comment: Can you please share your plugin and di.xml code in your question?

Comment: added, please check it you get something it will be a great help

Comment: Change `public function afterValidate(Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model)` with `public function afterValidate(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model, $result)` and try again

Comment: Not working, I added as per you comment

Comment: Have you run the deployment as well?

Comment: Yes, I ran deplyoment commands

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98234/discussion-between-sumit-and-arjun).