# How can I override following file?

Tags: magento2, overrides, sales-rule

[image]

In the above attach file I want to change

> `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address`

to

> Company\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address

Answer (score 0):

> Create di.xml file in Company\SalesRule\etc folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" type="Company\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" />
</config>
```

> Create Address.php file in Company\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition
>   folder

```
<?php

 namespace Company\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition;

class Address extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address
{
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below step to override `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address`

> File path: magento/app/code/Company/SalesRule/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_SalesRule" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Company/SalesRule/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Company_SalesRule',
__DIR__
);
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Company/SalesRule/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" type="Company\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address" />
</config>
```

> File path: magento/Company/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Address.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition;

class Address extends \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition
{
    /* You can write code hear as you want to need changes */

}
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but not working as the function validate() in which want to make change is added in Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address file & it doesn't get called on checkout page

Comment: Can you try to put complete `Address.php` file and just modify function validate() and check.

Comment: I tried that too but not working.

Answer (score 0):

## Create a basic module as Company/SalesRule

## Step 1 : Add di.xml file inside Company/SalesRule/etc folder with below content -

## Step 2 : Create Address.php with below content inside Company/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition folder

class Address extends \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition
{
   ** Write your methods here
}

Answer (score 0):

You can setup plugin instead of using preferences because validate() is public function and you can write plugin on it.

When setting up a new plugin for a class object, it will be defined in the di.xml file at app/code/{namespace}/{module}/etc/di.xml.Put the following code in di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address">
       <plugin name="Company_Salesrule_Address_Plugin" type="Company\SalesRule\Plugin\Rule\Condition\Address" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

You need to create file Address.php at Company\SalesRule\Plugin\Rule\Condition\ and add the following contents:

```
<?php

 namespace Company\SalesRule\Plugin\Rule\Condition\;

 class Address extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
 {
    //After methods take a responsibility of editing the results of an observed method
    public function afterValidate(Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address $subject, $result)
    {
          //Do your stuff here if you want to modify the result of validate()
    }

    //To apply the before methods for modifying the arguments of an observed method, you can return a modified argument.
    public function beforeValidate(Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address $subject, $customParameter)
    {
          //Do your stuff here if you want to modify the arguments of validate() before execution of it.
    }

   //Around methods allows the code to run before and after the observed method, so you can override a method.
    public function aroundValidate(Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
          //Do your stuff here if you want to modify the validate() method.
    }

 }
```

You can use any one the before, after, around method to achieve your requirements.

Refer this for more information for plugin https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html

I hope this solution work for you.

Comment: I have tried using the plugin method but getting error. Chk this link for error https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287409/getting-error-related-to-instance-of-for-abstract-model-class-when-trying-to-ove